# How to show that $f_n\to f$ on $[0,1]$ pointwise where $f(x)=1$ for rational $x$ and $0$ otherwise.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{r_n\}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1].$ Let $$f_n=\begin{cases}1&\text{if $x\in\{r_1,r_2,...,r_n\}$}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

I would like to show that $f_n\to f$ on $[0,1]$ pointwise where $f(x)=1$ for rational $x$ and $0$ otherwise.

That is I need to show that for any $x\in [0,1],\epsilon>0$ there exists $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$~\forall n\geq k,~~~|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$

I don't understand how could I get there!!

Help me.

Comment: how about x = 7/4? f(n)(7/4) = 0, but f(7/4)  = 1.

Comment: Hint: Split into two case: (1) $x$ is irrational (easier), and (2) $x = r_n$ for some $n$.

Comment: @LAcarguy Huh? 7/4 is not in [0,1].

Comment: @Did: he said in the definition that the " otherwise"part

Comment: Your "That is..." is the definition of **uniform** continuity.  You are not required to show that, and in fact it is false in this case.

Comment: @LAcarguy Yeah, and they asked for convergence **on [0,1]**.

Answer (score 4):

When $x$ is **irrational** for any $n\in\Bbb{N}$ we have $f_n(x)=0$ and so 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} 0=0$$
or in other word for given $\varepsilon>0$, it is enough to take $k=1$ because for for any $n\geq 1$ we have 
$|f_n(x)-0|=|0-0|=0<\varepsilon$

When $x$ is **rational** there exists a natural number $N_0\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $x=r_{N_0}$. So for any $n\geq N_0$,we have $x\in\{r_1,r_2,\cdots,r_{N_0},r_{N_0+1},\cdots,r_n\}$ and consequently for any $n\geq N_0$, we have $f_n(x)=1$. For given $\varepsilon>0$ it is enough to choose $k=N_0$ and then for any $n\geq k, |f_n(x)-1|=|1-1|=0<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show the apparently stronger but easier to prove statement that, for every $x$ in $[0,1]$, there exists some $N$ such that, for every $n\geqslant N$, $f_n(x)=f(x)$ (of course, this $N$ should depend on $x$).